# Pass password to sudo for command that expects input

Tags: shell, sudo

I am trying to create a Shell script and (to avoid typing, furthermore ignoring security related issues for now) want to directly pass the password to the "sudo" command, e.g.,

```
pword="mypassword"
echo $pword | sudo -S whoami
```

This works just fine. But now when the command itself expects an input, this method seems to fail, e.g.,

```
echo $pword | sudo -S cat<<<"Hello"
```

This would lead to an 'incorrect password' error. Currently, my solution is to run a "dummy command" like in example one first, and use the fact that for the second command the system does not prompt for a password again. However, does anyone know a better solution to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can defer the activation of the "here document" (the `<<<` construct) by doing something like this:

```
  echo $pw | sudo -S sh -c ' cat <<<"Hello" '
```

A better solution is to use `sudo -A` instead of `sudo -S`, after first defining a `$SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable to refer to a program that will emit your password.  Then you won't have to worry about competing for stdin with the rest of the command line.  You should create that askpass program (it can be a shell script) to be readable, writable and executable only by yourself so that your password will be securely hidden inside the program.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me when omitting the apostrophes `' '`, otherwise I receive a "Syntax error: redirection unexpected". I tried `sudo -A`, creating a script file echo'ing the password and setting `export SUDO_ASKPASS=/../that_script_file.sh`. Works great! However, I try to use the command on remote machines via ssh, and thus would need the password echo'ing script file on each machine. I tried to define a function within the script `function echo_pwd(){}`, but could not set `SUDO_ASKPASS` to that function (that's possible?).

Answer (score 0):

The **-v** flag of sudo is also useful if you have just entered your password for the SSH connection, **-v** updates the cache and doesn't ask for a password again:

```
sudo -v -u UserName && bash -c 'cat <<<"Hello"'
```